# MSOnline #Powershell

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-active-directory

**When I run this script **

```
    $Uppn = "XXX@ms.XX.XX"`
    $UserID = "00000"
    $DisName = "XXX XXXX "
    $FirstNm = "XXXX "
    $LastNm = "XXXX "
    $AltEmail = "xxxxxxx@xx.xx.xx.x"
    $Mobilenum = "+11111111111"
    New-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName $Uppn -ImmutableId $UserID -DisplayName $DisName -FirstName      $FirstNm -LastName $LastNm -AlternateEmailAddresses $AltEmail -LicenseAssignment   "aaa:STANDARDWOFFPACK_STUDENT" -UsageLocation "LK" -MobilePhone $Mobilenum`
```

**I get this issue**

```
    New-MsolUser : Unknown error occurred.
    At line:1 char:1

    + New-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName $Uppn -ImmutableId $UserID -DisplayNa ...
    + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  
     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo : OperationStopped: (:) \[New-MsolUser\], MicrosoftOnlineException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId :      Microsoft.Online.Administration.Automation.OperationNotAllowedException,Microsoft.Online.Administration.Automation.NewUser`
```

Any solutions?

i tried with different methods, cmdlet, Microsoft Graph PowerShell. I didn't get any good outcome :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cmdlet **Set-MsolUserLicense** and parameter **-LicenseAssignment** of cmdlet **New-MsolUser** are deprecated. Try using [Microsoft Graph PowerShell SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/enterprise/view-licenses-and-services-with-microsoft-365-powershell).

An example of creating a new user with command **New-MgUser** from this package can be seen [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.graph.users/new-mguser?view=graph-powershell-1.0). It should look something like this:

```
Connect-Graph -Scopes User.ReadWrite.All, Organization.Read.All
$PasswordProfile = @{
    Password = 'xWwvJ]6NMw+bWH-d'
}
New-MgUser -DisplayName 'Rene Magritte' -PasswordProfile $PasswordProfile -AccountEnabled -MailNickName 'ReneMagritte' -UserPrincipalName 'ReneMagritte@contoso.com'
$UserId = (Get-MgUser -ConsistencyLevel eventual -Count userCount -Filter "startsWith(DisplayName, 'Rene Magi')").Id
$EmsSku = Get-MgSubscribedSku -All | Where SkuPartNumber -eq 'aaa:STANDARDWOFFPACK_STUDENT'
Set-MgUserLicense -UserId $UserId -AddLicenses @{SkuId = $EmsSku.SkuId} -RemoveLicenses @()
```